# How to calculate all possible numbers that can result from adding, subtracting, or multiplying another list of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math

My latest hobby project to teach myself to code better by tossing challenges at myself that somehow benefit me.  This algorithm will basically be part of a solver I'm trying to make for a game I play that uses a bunch of simple math.

I have a list of between seven and nine numbers, each can can be any integer from 1-9, repeats are allowed.  So for example: `{6,3,8,9,1,3,7}`

I want to generate a second list of numbers (a set, no repeats here) that is all the possible results you can get by adding, subtracting, or multiplying the original numbers together.  Each number can only be used once unless it appears in the initial list multiple times.

- 6 (and all the other individual numbers)
- 6+3=9 (already have)
- 6+8=14
- ...all the addition ending with
- 6+3+8+9+1+3+7=37
- 6-3=3 (already have)
- 6-8= -2
- ...all the subtraction and then multiplication
- 6+3-8 = 1 (probably have by this point, but I need to calculate it anyways)
- ...etc. etc. ad nauseum

So I want each number by itself (easy), each number added/sub'd/mult'd to each other (easy), and then every possible combination of adding, sub'ing, and mult'ing.  *EDIT: I forgot to mention that for these purposes operation precedence (multiplication before addition/subtraction) isn't important.  The game I'm mimicking processes each operation individually so `6+1*7` would be 49, not 42.*

I've read up a little and I'm thinking that trees are going to be a big part of my solution, but I'm kind of at a loss as how to proceed.  I've had an introduction to trees, but I'm not comfortable enough with them to really understand how they may help me.  I will be putting this algorithm into code, most likely Java or a version of C.

As I mentioned, this is a self-improvement project so I don't just need a pre-coded solution, I'm sure *someone* on GitHub has done exactly this as some point.

Comment: It's not mentioned, but all your examples show the numbers in the same order as given. Do you need possibilities with them in *any* order? For example, `6*3+8=26`, but `6*8+3=51`.

Comment: Good point, and yes.  Isn't it wonderful how something so _simple_ becomes so _not_ once you actually start trying to do it?  Obviously I don't need to do 6*8 and 8*6 (although for simplicities' sake it'd be easy enough to calc that too rather than skipping it), but I would need `6*3+8` and `6*8+3` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:** So I can up with the following dynamic programming:

For set of number S we will call F(S) a set of all possible numbers, that can deduced from elements of S as described in the question.

For each subset S of a given set of numbers we will store the answer: F(S).

I calculate answer for a subset with the following algorithm:

1. All numbers from the set S are in F(S).
2. If number x is in subset S than we should add F(S - x) to F(S) because we are allowed to skip some numbers
3. Iterate through all subsets of S. Lets denote current subset as L and S - L as R. So for each number x in F(L), number y in F(R) and operator o in (+, -, *) we should add x o y to F(S).

In code we will represent a subset as a bit mask: if and only if i-th bit is one than i-th number is a part of the subset. So we have 2^9 subsets. Lets calculate answers for subsets in the order of bit masks from 1 to (1 << 9) - 1.

Code looks like this:

```
for (int mask = 1; mask < (1 << n); ++mask){
    set<int> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {           
        if (getBit(mask, i) == 1) { 
            result.insert(z[mask ^ (1 << i)].begin(), z[mask ^ (1 << i)].end()); //if we do not want to use some number, we erase it from the mask with xor
            result.insert(a[i]); // we always can take number itself if we have it in mask
        }
    }

    for (int left_mask = (mask - 1) & mask; left_mask > 0; left_mask = (left_mask - 1) & mask) { //this loop will iterate through all submasks of mask
        int right_mask = mask ^ left_mask;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int) z[left_mask].size(); ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < (int) z[right_mask].size(); ++j) {
                for (int op = 0; op < 3; ++op)
                    result.insert(applyOp(z[left_mask][i], z[right_mask][j], op));
        }
    }

    z[mask] = vector<int>(result.begin(), result.end());
}
```

So this works ~3 secs for 8 numbers and about a minute for 9 numbers, but there only one possible input with 9 numbers and 9 inputs with 8 numbers, so answers for them can be calculated in advance and stored. For 7 numbers this works around 300 milliseconds.

**Answer below is outdated and wrong because it does not consider cases like a*b + c*d**

I think bruteforce with memorization will work fast enought up to 9 numbers.
The state of bruteforce algorithm will be two integers: the current generated number and a bitmask of unused numbers from set. You just iterate through unused numbers and available operations and apply operation to current generated number and current unused number and update your state. Code will look like this:

```
vector<int> a; //initial numbers
set<int> result;
set< pair<int, int> > used; //visited bruteforces states

void brute(const pair<int, int>& state) {
    if (used.count(state)) 
        return;
    used.insert(state);
    result.insert(state.first);

    int current = state.first;
    int mask = state.second;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        if (((mask >> i) & 1) == 0) // if i-th bit is zero, then number is used
            continue;

        for (int op = 0; op < 3; ++op) {
            int next = current;
            if (op == 0)
                next += a[i];
            if (op == 1)
                next -= a[i];
            if (op == 2)
                next *= a[i];

            brute(make_pair(next, mask ^ (1 << i)));
        }
    }      
}
//...
// to start the process use brute(0, (1 << a.size()) - 1);
```

I ran this on my computer with all nine digits. It worked in ~2.5 secs and generated 192571 numbers. For 6 digits it works almost instantly. For 8 digits - ~300 milliseconds.

Comment: Actually, for my purposes on this project precedence doesn't matter, the situation I'm mimicking with code processes each operation individually before moving on to the next one.  But I totally forgot about precedence (and the lack thereof) in my original question, edited to include.  And it's a good note because in **most** coding situation precedence will matter quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to proceed (it is way the calculator does it) :-

> 1. Convert the set of numbers into infix expression
> 2. Do infix to postfix expression conversion
> 3. Solve postfix using stack
> 4. Store resultant numbers into hashset to reject duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

Nice question and funny to resolve. heres my solution . its a recursive method : ( it includes ur number in negatif also  which means if u have 3 in ur list , number -3is gonna be in the solution )

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test  {
static ArrayList<Integer> myresult =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    int[] a =  new int[]{3,5,7};

    for(int i = 0 ; i <  a.length ; ++i)
        calculate(a, 0 , 0);



    for(int j = 0 ; j <  myresult.size(); ++j)
        System.out.println("number " + j + " = " + myresult.get(j));
}
public static void calculate(int[] a , int initial , int leftvalues)
{
    if(leftvalues == (a.length-1) )
    {
        if(!myresult.contains(a[a.length-1]))
            myresult.add(a[a.length-1]);

        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        int add;
        int sub;
        for(int i = leftvalues ; i <  a.length ; ++i)
        {
            add = initial +  a[i];
            if(!myresult.contains(add))
                myresult.add(add);
            calculate(a , add,leftvalues+1);
            sub = initial -  a[i];
            if(!myresult.contains(sub))
                myresult.add(sub);
            calculate(a , sub,leftvalues+1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

hope this suits you well :)